# Modify my Tensorflow Lite output to process and display video frames sequentially

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, tensorflow-lite, android-mediacodec

I have this simple piece of code (from [here](https://github.com/lovelyzzkei/MobedSR)) that applies a TensorfFlow Lite model on an input image (of size 480x270) and after processing, it shows the resulting image. Works fine although the produced image looks very similar to the original. Now I need to extend it to videos. Basically instead of a single image, it should read frames of videos, apply the processing like what it does to an image, and sequentially display the resulting frames one after another (not by processing the entire video beforehand and then playing it).

How can I modify the code to achieve that?

[image]

```
package com.example.mobedsr;

import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.CompatibilityList;
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.ops.NormalizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ImageProcessor;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;


/** @brief  Super Resolution Model class
 *  @date   23/01/27
 */
public class SRModel {
    private boolean useGpu;

    public Interpreter interpreter;
    private Interpreter.Options options;
    private GpuDelegate gpuDelegate;
    private AssetManager assetManager;

    private final String MODEL_NAME = "evsrnet_x4.tflite"; //I want to change to esrgan.tflite

    SRModel(AssetManager assetManager, boolean useGpu) throws IOException {
        interpreter = null;
        gpuDelegate = null;

        this.assetManager = assetManager;
        this.useGpu = useGpu;

        // Initialize the TF Lite interpreter
        init();
    }

    private void init() throws IOException {
        options = new Interpreter.Options();

        // Set gpu delegate
        if (useGpu) {
            CompatibilityList compatList = new CompatibilityList();
            GpuDelegate.Options delegateOptions = compatList.getBestOptionsForThisDevice();
            gpuDelegate = new GpuDelegate(delegateOptions);
            options.addDelegate(gpuDelegate);
        }

        // Set TF Lite interpreter
        interpreter = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(), options);
    }

    /** @brief  Load .tflite model file to ByteBuffer
     *  @date   23/01/25
     */
    private ByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(MODEL_NAME);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

        FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = assetFileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();

        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }

    public void run(Object a, Object b) {
        interpreter.run(a, b);
    }


    /** @brief  Prepare the input tensor from low resolution image
     *  @date   23/01/25
     */
    public TensorImage prepareInputTensor(Bitmap bitmap_lr) {
        TensorImage inputImage = TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap_lr);
        int height = bitmap_lr.getHeight();
        int width = bitmap_lr.getWidth();

        ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .add(new ResizeOp(height, width, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
                .add(new NormalizeOp(0.0f, 255.0f))
                .build();
        inputImage = imageProcessor.process(inputImage);

        return inputImage;
    }


    /** @brief  Prepare the output tensor for super resolution
     *  @date   23/01/25
     */
    public TensorImage prepareOutputTensor() {
        TensorImage srImage = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);
//        int[] srShape = new int[]{1080, 1920, 3};
        int[] srShape = new int[]{1920, 1080, 3};
        srImage.load(TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(srShape, DataType.FLOAT32));

        return srImage;
    }


    /** @brief  Convert tensor to bitmap image
     *  @date   23/01/25
     *  @param outputTensor super resolutioned image
     */
    public Bitmap tensorToImage(TensorImage outputTensor) {
        ByteBuffer srOut = outputTensor.getBuffer();
        srOut.rewind();

        int height = outputTensor.getHeight();
        int width = outputTensor.getWidth();

        Bitmap bmpImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

        for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
            int a = 0xFF;
            float r = srOut.getFloat() * 255.0f;
            float g = srOut.getFloat() * 255.0f;
            float b = srOut.getFloat() * 255.0f;

            pixels[i] = a << 24 | ((int) r << 16) | ((int) g << 8) | ((int) b);
        }

        bmpImage.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        return bmpImage;
    }


}
```

Comment: Make sure the model is fast enough for this. Because according to the screenshot it takes 0.828 seconds to apply to an image. Video frame rate is usually 30 or 60 frames per second. In other words your model needs to process each frame in less than 1/60 of a second.

Comment: Yes I know. On GPU it takes much less. But regardless it is fine at this point; I just want to visualize it for video, even if fps is like 3.

Comment: I would start by exploring this demo app: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/video_classification/android. It processes frames from the Camera. Then you can build on top of it by decoding video frames using the MediaCodec.

Comment: Cool. But that is on camera frames, also written in kotlin that I don't know. I think it should be just reading frames one by one in a loop and run the model on.

Comment: You can read about video decoding here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec. And don't forget to convert YUV to RGB (it's shown in the demo app above).

Comment: There is also a higher level `Media3` library that you could use for decoding. Here are its demo apps: https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/release/demos

Comment: What are the benefits of using this decoding library?

Comment: I hope you could post an answer too based on your recommendations

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the model is fast enough for the task. Video frame rate is usually 30 or 60 frames per second. In other words your model needs to process each frame in less than 1/60 of a second.

In order to process video frames you need to decode them. You can use the [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) API for this. The documentation has example code.

The output buffer from the decoder contains the pixel data of a decoded video frame. Note that pixel colors are normally represented in the `YCbCr` color model (colloquially called `YUV`). More details in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/ImageFormat#yuv_420_888). And you will probably need to convert them to `RGB` before processing. See an example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/video_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/videoclassification/CalculateUtils.kt).

When you finally draw the processed result you will need to control the playback speed according to the presentation time of each frame. This can be done using the [Choreographer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer) for example.

There is also a higher level [Media3](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3) library which uses the `MediaCodec` internally and handles frequent use-cases (e.g. playback, resizing, basic transformations). You might find something useful in their [demos](https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/release/demos).

Comment: Thanks. But can you add that to my code and post it? I want a working solution

Comment: SO is a place where people share their knowledge. If you are looking for a service where somebody writes the code for you, then this is the wrong place.